# Discussion Tab in the side panel of each question

Tags: feature-request

I want to suggest to add a Discussion Tab in the side panel of each question. I think it will help users to discuss about the topic with out interfering with in the comments and share their thought about the topic. As it is Electrical Engineering forum such tab might be helpful for multiple reason. Beginners would get chance to raise thought without disturbing the main purpose of the question, experts can give suggestion and help improve the context about the topic.

Comment: As currently suggested, this would be a network-wide change and therefore would need to be posted on [main meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com). **Warning:** if you suggest it on main meta you should put a lot of thought into it, as users on main meta will likely downvote (to indicate disagreement) a suggestion that hasn't been seriously considered by the asker. Alternatively, you can use a chat room on the question for further discussion -- that is already in place.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because while its nice to get feedback on ideas, this idea could not be implemented on EE.SE

Comment: @Ankit_Gunner As well as the points raised by others it's worth noting that the site strongly aioms at Question and answer with discussion being minimised. Comments are already meant to be about the question and not about the technical aspect, but already get used for substantial technical input. I'd probably be happy with such some version of such a feature, but it would never achieve site-wide acceptance. || The fundamental aim of the site is to provide good Q&A that attracts search engine traffic that makes money for the owners :-). All the rest is a bonus :-)

Comment: The [chat feature](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=electronics.stackexchange.com) effectively handles this request, if (in my own opinion) not exceptionally well.

Comment: Thank you all for your views on this suggestion. I really appreciate your thoughts on this idea. I do see the idea  is a network-wide change rather than just EE. Yes, chat feature does deal with this issue but I think it is an isolated way to discuss rather than open panel for a topic you just came across. like @RussellMcMahon said fundamental aim is Q&A so I guess this is not the place for such panel. A version or plugin of such type would be Awesome. Moreover, Is there any other highly active discussion site out there rather than this for EE?

Comment: @Ankit_Gunner there is also a chat feature, SE is not intended for discussion, it's a Q&A site we rely on SE to make changes to the site

Comment: @Ankit_Gunner For a forum that supports discussion I suggest that you look at http://www.piclist.com (don't be put off by the presentation or the PIC in the name). Then visit http://mailman.mit.edu/mailman/listinfo/piclist, join the mailing list & say hello. Provide as much detail of your requirements as possible. 
 Just like here, there are people there who know almost everything (collectively). The site supports a conversational approach. Some SE members are also PICList members (myself included). It's a very useful complement to this site for questions of this sort.

Comment: Thank you @RussellMcMahon, I really appreciate you help. I am a recent EE graduate. I want to learn more and Network with people interested in this field. Your suggestion would really help me grow, thank you.

Comment: @VoltageSpike I do understand now, Thank you!!

Comment: anytime, Your welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The site already has a comments section, and so having two areas to have discussion would be redundant. This would need to be site wide and site wide features are decided by stack exchange.