# How to open linked Chat about question manually?

Tags: support, chat

In a [recent question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/644633/dc-stability-issue-with-this-audio-amplifier), jonk and I had an extended discussion in the comments and we realized that this would be better suited to the chatroom feature. But we didn't know how to open such a room. To be specific, I am interested in [a "linked" chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140995/discussion-on-question-by-mtx4-dc-stability-issue-with-this-audio-amplifier), that:

- is accessible via a link in comments of the specific question and
- which has a link to the question in the chatroom.

Eventually, a mod created this room, as happens for many questions. Is this possible without mod intervention? Indeed, n the recent [question here in meta about a "Discussion Tab" for questions](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9765/discussion-tab-in-the-side-panel-of-each-question), several users suggested to use the chatroom feature instead.

But currently, I only know how to open generic chat rooms in the chat feature, which is a fatal flaw IMO. I have two reasons for using chat: 1) General EE talk is catered to by the main room, and 2) question specific talk which only really makes sense when linked to a question.

**How to open linked question-specific chatrooms manually**, i.e. without spamming the comments section until a mod opens a room?

Comment: Related? [Should "move-to-chat" be provided on demand (as a button perhaps)?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100967/should-move-to-chat-be-provided-on-demand-as-a-button-perhaps)

Comment: @toolic I take your comment as an indirect way of saying "This is not possible manually" ?!

Answer (score 4):

As you've noted, you typically need either the system to prompt you to create the room or a moderator to create one for you.

The closest that a non-moderator can come to doing this manually (that I know of) is to:

1. Create a chat room with the correct site as the chat room parent. You can give the chat room a name which mimics the name automatically generated for system-linked chat rooms: "Discussion on [...]".
2. Link to the post in the chat room (e.g. as a chat message).
3. Comment on the post with a link to the chat room.

That's a lot of manual work (which is really unnecessary since the system is clearly capable of doing it for you) but it does satisfy your two bullet points.

Comment: @tobalt - considering that the Stack Overflow Meta question toolic linked to is over 11 *years* old, I wouldn't hold too much hope for the future anytime soon ... ;P

Comment: Unfortunately, given the two choices: a) the one you describe and b) abusing the comments section for chat until mod intervention, it appears quite clear which route most users will take. Well maybe there's hope for the future as shown in the links by toolic